# How to create a local schema in Oracle database 11g?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64). How do I create a new schema or local schema?

Comment: Any particular reason why you've installed an obsolete version of the database???

Comment: the internship supervisor asked me to install this version,i don't have a particular reason for that .

Answer (score 1):

A schema is the collection of objects owned by a user.

So connect as a power user like SYSTEM and run a `create user` command. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-USER.html#GUID-F0246961-558F-480B-AC0F-14B50134621C).

Once you have a user you can connect to it and create tables and other objects.

Comment: An important side note: DO NOT CREATE OBJECTS SUCH AS TABLES, VIEWS, PROCEDURES, PACKAGES, ETC IN THE SYS OR SYSTEM SCHEMAS, for this way lies m̶̵a̡d̢͠n̕e͜҉s̸̵s͡҉...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in the docs?  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6014.htm#SQLRF01313

In oracle a 'schema' is nothing more than the collection of objects belonging to a given user. Many people will even argue that a "user" *is* a "schema".  I believe that it was with 11g (now out of support) that oracle introduced the CREATE SCHEMA command.  That command simply combines creating a user and creating some tables belonging to that user into a single SQL statement.  You can always do it the "old fashioned" way by simply issuing a CREATE USER, then issuing whatever CREATE   .  statements you need:

```
create user fubar identified by fubar;
create table fubar.mytable (dob date);
create view fubar.myview as (select * from fubar.mytable);
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Stack Overflow - the world's go-to site for to-order Google searches...